Similarity Component Analysis
I am working on comparing components obtained by running independent Component Analysis (ICA) on different gene expression matrices. I ran into a paper (https://schangpi.github.io/papers/nips13_sca.pdf) where I think the problem described could be adapted and used in gene expression analysis. The author described a non-metric learning process which was called Similarity Component Analysis.
My question: is there any R or Python implementation of this method or something very closely related?

Software related questions may be more suitable on stackoverflow.
